# Why is the keyword 'then' required in KRL

Tags: grammar, krl

When I'm writing a conditional action block in a KRL rule I always forget the 'then' keyword. Here is the correct syntax:

```
rule with_conditions {
  select when pageview ".*"
  pre {
    cheese = "Camembert";
  }
  if (cheese like re/bert/) then {
    notify("Odd Cheese", "#{cheese} is unusual.");
  }
  fired {
    raise explicit event "odd_cheese";
  }
}
```

Why 'then'? Wouldn't it be just as clear without it?

Comment: Tags SO rejected: cheese, little things that drive you nuts.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would +1 using then to increase ease of learning. When I was first beginning to program, I hated that then was left out of mostly easy to read Python scripts.

Comment: Guess I'm so used to languages without 'then' (javascript, python) that it always trips me up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because the writers of the language felt that adding `then` was more natural.

Comment: Tim here is correct. It does help if you remember that parens () are optional: if cheese like re/bert/ then {}

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess this allows stuff like: if cheese like re/bert/ then notify("French Cheese", "Hope you have a valid passport!");